# VBA convert my decimal number to formula separator

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I try to make a formula in vba and I have a problem.
For example in cell C2 I have a decimal number "4,62" and when I try to use it in a formula, VBA take the comma as a separator.

VBA Code:

```
Sheets("Feuil4").Range("C3").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("C2") & ",[@[Prix total ens]])"
```

If @[Prix total ens] = 5, the final result will be 71 (4+62+5).
How can I make the comma read as a comma and not a separator ?

Btw I'm French so I know that for most of you, you will written 4.62
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheets("Feuil4").Range("C3").Formula = "=SUM(C2,[@[Prix total ens]])"`

Comment: @Eraaz No problem. If you end up needing the formula text to be more dynamic then for any range Object you could use the .Address property (e.g. ```= "=SUM(" & rng.Address & ",[@[Prix total ens]])"```)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your list seperator from windows regional settings.

Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Regional Options Tab. > Customize / Additional settings > Type a new separator in the "List separator" box. > OK > OK

Comment: other people will use the file, so it's not going to be very practical ...

Answer (score 0):

Reading a decimal number from Excel and using it in VBA is quite a pain, if the Excel uses comma as a decimal separator (German and French Excel).

The work around I have developed is the following function:

```
Public Function ChangeCommas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String
    
    Dim temp As String    
    temp = CStr(myValue)
    ChangeCommas = Replace(temp, ",", ".")
    
End Function
```

In your case:

`Sheets("Feuil4").Range("C3").Formula = "=SUM(" & ChangeCommas(Range("C2")) & ",[@[Prix total ens]])"`